# animate jQuery attribute can't use variables?

Tags: javascript, jquery

After declaring `height()` variables for multiple loaded elements which have different variables for each, the `animate()` function doesn't seem to be loading the variable `excHeight`.

What would be the best way to use the value of `excHeight` for the `animate()` as below?

```
$(".exPand a").click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var post_id = $(this).attr("rel");

    var postHeight = $(this).closest('.boxy')
                            .find('.articleImageThumb')
                            .height();

    var excHeight = $(this).closest('boxy')
                           .find('.articleImageThumb')
                           .find('.initialPostLoad')
                           .height();

    $.ajaxSetup({cache:false});

    $(this).closest('.boxy')
           .animate({height: postHeight+excHeight}, 1000);

    $(this).closest('.boxy')
           .find('.articleImageThumb')
       .animate({top: 0}, 1000);

    $(this).closest('.boxy').find('.articleTitle')
    .animate({bottom: excHeight}, 1000);

    $(this).closest('.boxy').find('.postmetadata')
    .animate({bottom: excHeight}, 1000);
});
```

Comment: do a `console.log(excHeight)` first and you will see the problem

Comment: Wrap **postHeight+excHeight** in small brackets and see what happens i.e. **(postHeight+excHeight)**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like it is not working because you forgot "dot" in `boxy` class name: `var excHeight = $(this).closest('boxy')` , must be like this: `var excHeight = $(this).closest('.boxy')`

Comment: Hah! Haven't had my coffee yet... Thanks